# What is Core Affect?

Tags: emotion, well-being, definition

Can someone explain what is core affect however for a person without much understanding in psychology? I have a book which mentions that core affect generally can tell you for example if you are OK or not OK -- but does it take into account also your thoughts? Or it is purely based on being OK from **physical standpoint**? e.g. if it senses some physical danger then core affect goes into negative state. But if we are in a situation with negative thoughts for example -- is core affect also related to this?